# Effective timestamp serializing in Python

Tags: python, serialization, timestamp

I got time stamp when I print `time.time()`.

```
In [48]: print time.time()
1370898402.64
```

How can I serialize it as a string?
I thought about transforming it into a string as follows:

```
"%s" % time.time()
```

I use 13 bytes for the storage, but I hope I can save some bytes if I can serialize the timestamp.

Comment: What are you doing with it?

Comment: @Blender: I need to send the timestamp data over the network

Answer (score 1):

If you can deal with a 1-second granularity, it's easy to print it out as hex, gets you down to 8 bytes:

```
>>> "%x" % int(time.time())
'51b642e9'
```